# Enable Flash plugin in WPF using CEFSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, cefsharp

I'm developing a WPF application using Cefsharp. This web browser inside the app should show some flash contents. I found some forum where the users suggest to use papi flash or pepper flash for Cefsharp.
I have no idea how to implement those plugin in my project.
I'm using the last version of Cefsharp.
Someone can explain how to enable Flash contents in my webview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the `PPAPI` version of Flash. Every computer running your app must do the same. Visit http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ and select `FP [xx] for Chromium and Opera` where `[xx]` is the current version number, which is `26` at the time of this answer.

Comment: Is there another way to include this PPAPI in the application?

Comment: You could make the flash installation as part of your build scripts (this is a new question), but it's not unreasonable to expect users to install plugins like flash themselves.